# How can I override the behavior of the division operator?

Tags: javascript, overwrite, operand

When dividing in JS you get `Infinity` if you divide by zero, I want to change that behavior by returning `undefined` so I can identify a real `Infinity` vs. an error result.

Assuming that writing the next line calls some math or build-in function for division:

```
var a = 6 / 0;
```

1. What is the full name/path of the '/' function ?
2. Is there a way to overwrite it (or any other operand)?

---

A sharpening:

`Infinity / 1 = Infinity` (the top Infinity is a result from a devision by zero) whereas `undefined / 1 = Nan`.
Is it possible **without writing and using my own function** to identify that there was a problem in during the calculation?

Comment: any help - stackoverflow.com/questions/4724555/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-evaluates-to-infinity ?

Comment: WTH do you consider to be "*a real Infinity*"?

Comment: I understand now that there is now Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`/` is not a function in JavaScript, it's an operator, so you can't override it.

You can, however, write a function to protect division:

```js
function divide (a, b) {
    return b === 0 ? undefined : a / b;
}
```

and use it like so:

```js
var a = divide(6, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is just an **arithmetic operator** that is used for division purposes.

You cannot override it. However, you can use an if else block to check for the **infinity** value, and change it to undefined.